# VS2010 Ultimate beta 2: Where is application verifier?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, application-verifier

In VSTS2008 there used to be `Debug -> Start With Application Verifier`, which doesn't exist in VS2010 Ultimate beta 2. Where has it gone?

Answer (score 1):

See this [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/07/27/visual-studio-2010-rip-list-partial.aspx).  Application verifier is no longer integrated into VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The magic for App Verifier is in the debugger.  The utility just sets the registry keys the debugger uses.

You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c4a25ab9-649d-4a1b-b4a7-c9d8b095df18&displaylang=en).

Comment: VS TS 2008 had more to it than just setting some keys in the registry. It didn't answer it for me, and I'm sure it didn't answer it for this poor guy who asked the question originally.

Comment: Well, if a link to the place to install Application Verifier isn't enough, I'm not sure what would be.

Comment: The version of AppVerifier in the link does not work with Intel Core i7 CPU's.

Comment: I was not aware of that.  I bet one could use google to find the correct version.  All it does is set some registry keys anyway, which can be set manually.